# Change tracking information using DbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

In reading an article on [N-Tiered Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321569.aspx#id0090007), I came across information regarding concurrency tokens and change tracking information:

> Another important concept to understand is that while the
>   default-generated entities support serialization, their
>   change-tracking information is stored in the ObjectStateManager (a
>   part of the ObjectContext), which does not support serialization.

My question is three-fold:

1. Is there the same thing when using `DbContext`?
2. If the only interaction with the database is in a `Repository` class within a `using` statement, does closing the database connection when the program leaves the `using` statement get rid of any option for change tracking?
3. Can this be leveraged as/with a Concurrency Token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. `DbContext` is just wrapper around `ObjectContext` and it exposes change tracking information through `ChangeTracker` property (returns `DbChangeTracker`) and for particular entity through calling `Entry` method (returns `DbEntityEntry<T>`).
2. Yes. Closing context will remove all change tracking information.
3. Concurrency token and change tracking are two completely different concepts. Change tracking tells context what operations it has to execute on database when you call `SaveChanges`. It tracks changes you did on your entities since you loaded them into current context instance. Concurrency token resolves optimistic concurrency in the database => it validates that another process / thread / user / context instance didn't change the same record your context is going to modify during `SaveChanges`.